# How to make this jQuery Vertical News Scroller NOT repeat/loop

Tags: jquery, repeat, scroller

I found this scroller that I would like to use, however, I want it to stop after showing the last item.

http://www.cre.lt/tadas/vticker.php

Is it possible?

Tracy

Comment: The code is kind of confusing to me, but you will need to use clearInterval(interval); at some point. The variable in the .js file is actually named interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [code](http://www.cre.lt/tadas/jquery.vticker.js) and there is no support for stopping after it is done looping once. I mean to say there is no such option/setting available for doing that. But you can use the same code and tweak to work, I haven't tried this one, but try commenting the line `first.appendTo(obj.children('ul'));` and see. It should show once and will not repeat.

Comment: FYI: It will not cause the timer to stop as noted by @flipflopmedia in the comments but it will loop only once.

Comment: Wow! I'm glad you FYI'd that! It got my attention, tried it and it's beautiful! That's all I want it to do, is go away when it's done with it's first round. Thank you! I love this place, you guys are brilliant! :)